# Parsing a text file and sorting it by an option with Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to parse 3 different`txt` files which contain contact info like `Abercrombie, Neil, Male, Tan, 2/13/1943`.

Each file uses different delimiters despite having the same info: one uses a comma, one uses a pipe, and one uses spaces.

The goal here is to be able to read the `txt` files format them, and sort them by a given option; could be by gender, by birth date, and by the last name.

I'm trying to figure out what exact methods will be required of me, and if I should even make a class for this. I have a couple of ideas since I feel like there are a thousands way to write it. I'm open to suggestions though. The methods will also be tested.

```
import sys
import os

def main():
   filepath = sys.argv[1]
   sortOption = sys.argv[2]    

   if not os.path.isfile(filepath):
       print("File path {} does not exist. Exiting...".format(filepath))
       sys.exit()

   with open(filepath) as fp:
       for line in fp:
                    formatPerson(line)

def formatPerson(line):
    # delimiter = ... find the delimiter for each line and split the string as so
    person = line.strip().split(delimiter);
    return person

def formatDate(line):
    # read line and re-format the date

def sortContacts(option):
    # read all lines and sort them by the option

def sortByGender():
    # Read all contacts and sort them by gender

def sortByBirthdate():
    # Read all contacts and sort them by birthdate

def sortByLastname():
    # Read all contacts and sort them by last name

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

An example output would look like this:

```
Hingis Martina Female 4/2/1979 Green
Kelly Sue Female 7/12/1959 Pink
Kournikova Anna Female 6/3/1975 Red
Seles Monica Female 12/2/1973 Black
Abercrombie Neil Male 2/13/1943 Tan
Bishop Timothy Male 4/23/1967 Yellow
Bonk Radek Male 6/3/1975 Green
Bouillon Francis Male 6/3/1975 Blue
Smith Steve Male 3/3/1985 Red
```

Comment: lots of methods that do nothing. some code that does read something maybe. no splitting at all (or rather not storing the splitted results at all). Why dont read about module CSV and how to specify the delimiter? What is your specific problem that is not yet handled on SO? reading from file is, splitting csv is, putting data in lists is, sorting lists of lists by a key-value is, ...

Comment: Have you already took a look at the popular library `pandas`? It makes it very easy to read txt (csv) files and sort them. The methods you need are `read_csv() ` and `sort_values() ` of the pandas library.

Comment: You're calling `formatPerson()` but not saving the returned data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `csv` module. You can set the delimiter it uses to read files, differently for each file. If you know that in advance and can hardcode that information into the program, that's an option; otherwise, you might be able to just use the first character in the line that isn't alphanumeric or whitespace:

```
# use regex to find the first character in the file that isn't whitespace
with open("my_file.csv", "r") as infile:
    file_lines = infile.readlines()
    delimiter = re.search("\w+([^\w])", file_lines[0]).group(1)
    ...
```

Then, open the file with the `csv` module:

```
reader = csv.reader(file_lines, delimiter=delimiter)
line_list = [row for row in reader]
# line_list is now a 2D list, where each element of the outer list is a list of tokens
#   on that row of the CSV file
```

and now, you can sort `line_list` however you need to, by giving the built-in `sorted()` function a custom key to sort by:

```
sorted_by_lastname = sorted(line_list, key=lambda elem:elem[0])
sorted_by_firstname = sorted(line_list, key=lambda elem:elem[1])
...
```